# What is the arr[condition] operation called in numpy Python?

Tags: python, numpy

```
array = np.arange(10)

array_odd = array[array % 2 == 1]
```

I have tried looking in the documentation and cannot find it. What is this operation called?

Comment: Filtering? Indexing?

Comment: [boolean array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing)

Comment: Is it Slicing? Sometime array.loc[index] or just array[index] isvworking. I don't really know why

Comment: @dimz, `pandas` uses `loc`, `numpy` does not.

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad